# How to add Facebook Credits to test user

Tags: facebook, testing, facebook-credits

I [created a Facebook test user](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) for my [Lovers Facebook application](http://apps.facebook.com/mylovers/), and I'm using this user to test the [Facebook Credits API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi/). But, when I click the link to make an order, I am presented with a Facebook Dialog titled, "Buy Red Rose" I'm asked for my credit card info because the test user doesn't have enough credits. How do I add Facebook credits to a test user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. No need to create a test user. You can just add your user id in the text field labeled Credits Test Users on the Credits tab of the Edit Application Settings page => http://www.facebook.com/developers/editapp.php?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID

Comment: where is this on new FB layout :S

Comment: new layout is settings->payment, turns out I didn't have permission