# FacebookCredits - add credits to test users

Tags: java, facebook-credits, restfb

I'm looking for another answer than the one stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980463/how-to-add-facebook-credits-to-test-user). I want to see the credits "transfered" in my app. Insights but with test users transactions, in order to ensure that callback has no mistakes. I'm afraid it can't be done, but if someone has another option, that could be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only options are to use testers, and live with the fact that their transactions won't appear in the payout reports, or use real credits and real money

Comment: Yep, after cribing into lot of documentation I got that point, thanks Igy. The only thing Facebook does is refunding the money one spends (if they want, of course).